# How to send Spark Streaming data from a server side to a client with Websockets?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-storm, apache-spark

In Apache Storm, **Apache Camel** can be used **to subscribe** an ActiveMQ queue where storm bolts write their outputs to and **to push** these outputs to WebSockets, therefore, the client can get these streaming data after a correct handshake, as shown in [this website](http://blog.avisi.nl/2013/07/01/tools-for-building-a-real-time-analytics-platform/).

Is there any method similar to this in sending Spark Streaming data from a server side to a client with Websockets in Java? If not, are there any other better solutions in Java or Scala?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use RabbitMQ.  Have Spark as a Producer to the RabbitMQ queue. Then use a RabbitMQ Consumer that writes the data over WebSockets to your HTML client.

The original approach was to use Kafka. But there are serious bugs in that framework. I will revisit Kafka in 0.8.2 release after these bugs are (hopefully) fixed.

BTW the WebSockets solution was quite a bear. I ended up writing my own solution on top of a small library on Netty  -since there were issues in the readily available ones (socko, spray, play,etc)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) is very powerful. Your solution works in my project. I found that using [server sent events(SSE)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) can feel less pain, but WebSockets is better than SEE, since it supports bidirectional communication.